# react-native run-android Cannot get property 'packageName' on null object

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I have been learning React-native for just a few days. I have been following the "Getting started - React Native" for ubuntu + android in React Native official docs. However, I cannot get through this error while running: **sudo react-native run-android**

```
Cannot get property 'packageName' on null object
```

This error seems to related to "Gradle". I have no idea how to fix as well as debugging it. Please, can anyone help me figure out this matter?

Comment: Please check that the order of execution is correct  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Comment: As you are firing **sudo** commands it means you are of need admin rights to run project. Is there a **lock** icon over project folder

Comment: I have followed exactly the same as their instructions, I have used sudo in every command and there is no lock icon over the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Do following things:

1. If lock icon is shown on  project folder
   then gave permission using --- chown -R   and Enter.
   Go to location of main project a folder in terminal and fire command.
2. Then from terminal run **react-native run-android**

Comment: I have already set permission as 777 and owner as my root user then run "sudo react-native run-android" but nothing has changed..

Comment: @HungDQ What else console print or share screen shot of error

Answer (score 0):

This may resolve the issue. Try [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/655#issuecomment-534523442)